# How do I validate multiple inputs for a function?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a "Validator" class which allows us to set values of its member variables (mostly boolean) - mv1, mv2, mv3 etc. with setter methods. Lets call all these variables "settings". All the setter methods return this Validator instead of the usual void. A Validator is setup and then used by automation test methods to validate the json/string response body of an api call made in the test method.

The Validator has a validate(Input input) method which takes an "Input" object (actually an api response) and validates it based on the values of settings of Validator. There are some dependencies between the various settings. For example, if mv1 = true, then mv3 cannot be true etc. Also, I cannot always use enums to restrict the values of the settings !

I validate all the settings with validateSettings(). The validate(Input input) calls it before doing the validation. I want to find out all the invalid inputs, display them all at once and then prevent the validation until the inputs are fixed. **What is the best way to do this in Java ?**

**What did I try ?**

Using plain Java -
I used a string to store all the invalid settings and with reasons why they are invalid. Then, throw an IllegalArgumentException if one or more settings were found to be invalid and pass it the string. I want to avoid writing custom code if possible. I also don't want to use Java's assert because it can be disabled at run time.

Using TestNg library-
I use a SoftAssert to validate the member variables. The code inspects some of the the member variables, asserts that the variables have valid values and finally does softAssert.assertAll() to list all the wrong values at once. But, I wonder if Java has any in-built features to do this.

```
class Validator {

    // Validator settings
    boolean mv1;
    boolean mv2;
    boolean mv3;
    boolean mv4;
    boolean mv5;
    //MyEnum mv6;//...etc.

    // Setters - One example.
    public Validator setMv1(boolean mv1) {
        this.mv1 = mv1;
        return this;
    }

    // Validation logic
    public void validate(Input input) {
        validateSettings();
        // Now, validate the input.
    }

    // Validate the settings of this Validator - using TestNg library
    private void validateSettings() {
        SoftAssert assertz = new SoftAssert();
        // No need to validate all settings ! Only some needed.
        if (mv1 == true) {
            assertz.assertFalse(mv3, "Meaningful error message");
            assertz.assertTrue(mv5, "Meaningful error message");
        }
        // Assert other things.
        assertz.assertAll();
    }

    // Validate the settings of this Validator - using plain Java.
    private void validateSettingsV1() {
        String errors = "These are the invalid settings - ";
        boolean areSettingsInvalid = false;
        if (mv1 == true) {
            if (mv3 == true) {
                errors += "mv3 can't be true when...blah";
                areSettingsInvalid = true;
            }
            if (mv5 == false) {
                errors += "mv5 can't be false when...blah";
                areSettingsInvalid = true;
            }

            // Repeat above logic for all invalid settings.

            if (areSettingsInvalid == true) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(errors);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am somewhat confused. What should happen if the `validateSettings()` fails? It should notify the user and then give them some way to update the settings, and repeat that until the settings are correct so we can continue with the input validation?

Comment: @mapeters - If it fails, then the automation test code which calls validate() method should fail and all the invalid settings should be printed to the console, with reasons as to why they are invalid. I.e we correct the settings we are passing in our automation test code and then re-run until validation can be done.

Comment: @mapeters - I updated my question and cleaned up the code a bit.

Comment: Why would `validateSettings` ever fail? Are the settings provided by the end user as well or it's a programmers error? A `Validator` should most likely never be allowed to be in an invalid state. I'd use a factory to construct `Validator` instances.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 - It looks to be a good usecase for TestNG `SoftAsserts` because first, you capture all assertion failures and report them in one shot, and second because its an assertion error, the caller is guaranteed to fail (since the caller in your case is a test method)